# How to use strtok properly to compare versions?

Tags: c, string-comparison, software-design, strtok

I am trying to write a **C program** which **compares 2 software version numbers** (in the format "12.3.2", "2.10", "6.0.0.3" or "2.0") **using strtok** in C. *Also 1.0 is considered bigger than 1.* So, basically, **compares 2 strings** that represent version numbers. Trying to figure out a way for the code to work. I'm stuck at the point that how could I store these tokens? And then how could I compare them later? 
So if:

```
v1>v2 : return 1, 
v1==v2:return 0 
v1<v2: return -1.
```

The function signature could be:

```
int cmp(char *v1, char *v2){...}
```

(v1 and v2 are the version numbers.)
Any suggestions? I'm practically new to C compared to Python or other object oriented programming languages(C#,java).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
struct version_t {
int major;
int minor;
int build;
```

};

```
version_t parse_ver(const char* version_str) {
   version_t res;
   version_t r;
   // Trying to use strtok_r to split the string, and atoi to convert 
   //tokens to ints
  char *token;
  char *rest = version_str;
  while((token = strtok_r(rest,".",&rest)))
  {
    res = token;
  }
  r = atoi(res);
  return r;
 }
```

Initially I am just considering that versions are in the format 12.3.4(3 fields). I'm not sure how I could work with other sorts of version numbers like 1.34.2.5 or 1.0

I would then use the parse_ver function twice to parse both the version numbers. If I could get the tokens and return them as integers I would later use a compare function to compare those integers and solve this problem. 
I wrote a small program to check how strtok works and I got the idea by writing something as the following:

```
void main(void)
{
  char str[] = "1.2.3.4";
  char *token;
  char *rest = str;

  while((token = strtok_r(rest, ".", &rest)))
  {
    printf("token:%s\n", token);

  }
}
```

But I need to store the tokens in the struct somehow. Slightly confused here.

Again, I'm pretty new to the C programming language and any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @DavidBowling Isn't it simpler to use atoi() insead?

Comment: Isn't strtok obsolete? Use split.

Comment: @Marichyasana-- `strtok()` is not obsolete as of the C11 Standard, and there is no `split()` function in the Standard C Library.

Comment: @Marichyasana split() is a more Pythonic way of doing things. The question was C specific.

Comment: I may be wrong but doesn't strtok modify the source string? So not work with  const char[]

Comment: @DavidBowling 'Software Engineering Institute' at CMU seems to think it is obsolescent though https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC24-C.+Do+not+use+deprecated+or+obsolescent+functions

Comment: @Marichyasana-- those are the CERT Secure Coding Standards; `strtok()` is listed under _Unchecked Obsolescent Functions_, along with `fprintf()`, `qsort()`, `memcpy()`, `sscanf()`, and a host of others that see regular use in code that is not mission critical. Further, this is listed not under **Rules**, but under **Recommendations**. The recommendation is not to use deprecated or obsolescent functions when more secure functions are available; note that the suggested replacement for `strtok()` is `strtok_s()`, from Annex K, which is optional and thus not portable.

Comment: @Marichyasana-- you are correct that `strtok()` modifies the parse string, and so will not work with a string literal, or with an array of `const char`s. But OP had `char str[] = "1.2.3.4";`, which is an initializer. Here, `str[]` is not a string literal, and is not `const`, so `strtok()` will work on this. If instead `char *str = "1.2.3.4"` were used, then there would be a problem because `str` would point to a string literal. BTW, that `strtok()` modifies the parse string is one of the issues that the CERT Standard has with `strtok()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strtol()` for this, taking advantage of the tail pointer and skipping over the decimal points. This would allow comparison of each field.

In the code below, starting from the first field, a positive value is returned if the first version number is greater than the second, or a negative value is returned if the first version number is less than the second. If the two version numbers are equal, the decimal point is skipped, and the next two fields are compared. If the the end of one string is reached and the fields have compared equal, the difference between the values indicated by the tail pointers is returned (so `1.0` is greater than `1`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ver_comp(char *, char *);

int main(void)
{
    char *ver1 = "12.3.2";
    char *ver2 = "2.10";
    printf("%s - %s = %d\n", ver1, ver2, ver_comp(ver1, ver2));

    ver1 = "2.10";
    ver2 = "6.0.0.3";
    printf("%s - %s = %d\n", ver1, ver2, ver_comp(ver1, ver2));

    ver1 = "2";
    ver2 = "2.0";
    printf("%s - %s = %d\n", ver1, ver2, ver_comp(ver1, ver2));

    ver1 = "2.0.0.1.2";
    ver2 = "2.0.0.2.2";
    printf("%s - %s = %d\n", ver1, ver2, ver_comp(ver1, ver2));

    ver1 = "1.2.3.4";
    ver2 = "1.2.3.4";
    printf("%s - %s = %d\n", ver1, ver2, ver_comp(ver1, ver2));

    return 0;
}

int ver_comp(char *v1, char *v2)
{
    int res = 0;
    char *next_1 = v1;
    char *next_2 = v2;

    while (*next_1 != '\0' && *next_2 != '\0') {
        long x1 = strtol(v1, &next_1, 10);
        long x2 = strtol(v2, &next_2, 10);

        res = x1 - x2;
        if (res) {
            break;
        }

        if (*next_1 == '\0' || *next_2 == '\0') {
            res = *next_1 - *next_2;
            break;
        }

        v1 = next_1 + 1;
        v2 = next_2 + 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Program output:

```
12.3.2 - 2.10 = 10
2.10 - 6.0.0.3 = -4
2 - 2.0 = -46
2.0.0.1.2 - 2.0.0.2.2 = -1
1.2.3.4 - 1.2.3.4 = 0
```

Comment: @coder1532-- you could probably use `strtok()` and store the results in an array if you need to keep the values from each of the fields, but I think that this method is simpler, if it compares the version numbers acceptably.

Comment: Extremely helpful and works perfectly. But just for the sake of clarity was my implementation of strtok incorrect? So if I store the values in an array, how should I use atoi() to convert them to ints? Also, the use of the struct I created was a bit of an unnecessary overkill you think?

Comment: Well, since `atoi()` is called outside of the loop, only the last token found is converted to an `int`. I think you meant to call this in the loop, and store the result in the appropriate field of your structure. But this would be easier to just store in an array with indices. You could count the number of fields first, then declare a VLA, and fill it with the version numbers.

Comment: Another option would be to copy the whole version number string into another array (so you don't modify the original), and then filter out all of the decimal points. Then use `strtol()` to convert this to an integer for comparison. I suggested this in an earlier comment; the reason for `strtol()` here is that it allows checks for integer overflow, in case of long version number strings. Such checks could be added to the above code, but this is unlikely to have overflow issues, since each field is converted separately.

Comment: Very useful. Acknowledged.